# Dealing with multiple strings and corresponding integers in a single cell

Tags: google-sheets

I’ve got a question about something I’m trying to achieve in Google spreadsheets. I’ve got the following table:

```
| NAME                    | COUNTRY              |
--------------------------------------------------
| Alpha                   | GER*1, SWE*3         |
--------------------------------------------------
| Beta                    | GER*5, SWE*1         |
--------------------------------------------------
| Gamma                   | SWE*5, GER*3         |
--------------------------------------------------
| Delta                   | SWE*2, GER*1         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now I’d like to be able to calculate how many SWE there are in line Gamma. I’d need spreadsheets to return an integer value, in my example the correct one would be 5.

However, I’d also like to be able to calculate the total number of GER in line Alpha to Delta, also returned as an integer value, in this case the result should be 1+5+3+1 = 10.

As you can see I’m dealing with both strings and integers in a single cell. If it would be possible to for example create an array of all GER*(INTEGER), then delete the GER* and have an array of only the integers that might help me?

I’ve searched here, googled around and fiddled with spreadsheets to try and come to a solution but either I’m too daft or it’s not as trivial as I thought it’d be. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the total number of GER in line Alpha to Delta (assuming your data extends from row 2 to row 5) , try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(B2:B5, "GER\*(\d+)")+0,0)))
```

To calculate how many SWE there are in line Gamma, try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(filter(B2:B6, A2:A6="Gamma"), "SWE\*(\d+)")+0,0)))
```

Change the ranges so that they suit your actual data range and see if that works ?

Comment: This works almost perfect. Thanks a bunch! When the string I’m looking for is not present in one line, there’s an error though: "does not match text of Function". If it would give me a 0 in that case that’d be it. Maybe if I use ISNA and if TRUE return 0? Sounds a bit too complicated, though.

Comment: Try catching the errors with IFERROR(). See my updated answer and check if it works.

Comment: Works like a charm. I had to make a minor adjustment (the underscore) but this is what it’s looking like right now: `=sum(ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(Location, "GER_(\d+)")+0,0)))` Thanks alot, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the Text functions, like `FIND` together with `MID`. `REGEXEXTRACT` is even more powerful but harder to use. When you have the substring, use `VALUE` to get the numeric value from it.

For the summary, the easiest is probably to create an extra column, extract the GER value into it as above, and `SUM` that column.

Here's the function reference for Google Spreadsheets: https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en